# Tkinter Canvas bind '<Configure>' event to item

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Am I missing something ? I thought I've done something like the example below.
But neither I found a script of mine that act like I hoped, nor I have found something online.
Basically I want to bind the *Configure* event to an item. Isnt it possible like the error suggest?

Resources : [Canvas](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M164) and [tag_bind](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/bindtags.htm)

```
import tkinter as tk

def do_something(event=None):
    print('something')
def stupid_workaround():
    if cnvs.coords(lbl) != lbl_coords:
        do_something()
        cnvs.coords(lbl, *lbl_coords)
    
    cnvs.after(200,stupid_workaround)

root = tk.Tk()
cnvs = tk. Canvas(root,highlightthickness=0)
lbl = cnvs.create_text(0,0, text='this is an exampel', anchor='nw')
lbl_coords = cnvs.coords(lbl)
btn = tk.Button(root, text='change coords', command=lambda:cnvs.coords(lbl,10,10))
btn.pack()
stupid_workaround()
#cnvs.bind(lbl, '<Configure>', do_something) #throws no error
#cnvs.tag_bind(lbl, '<Configure>', do_something) #throws error

cnvs.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

> _tkinter.TclError: requested illegal events; only key, button, motion, enter, leave, and virtual events may be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, you can't bind to the `<Configure>` event, it's simply not an option. That event is only valid for widgets, not items drawn on a canvas.