# How to call an event handler already bound to an image on tkinter canvas while drawing a line?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas, line

My app has 2 images on a canvas.
I want to connect those 2 images with a line.
The requirement is to have a context menu on a right click on the first image. The context menu has an option called "Start Connection". When this option is clicked, it draws a line starting from image1 to the current position of mouse pointer and then when the mouse click the image2, the connection will end at image2.
I am able to make the context menu bound to right click and the line follow the current mouse pointer. But now the problem is that when I click the image2, the single click event handler is not getting triggered even if I have bound it to the event.

instanceobj is object of some other class and is associated with the current image.

```
if_connection_started = False
start_x = 0
start_y = 0
end_x = 0
end_y = 0
start_instance = None
start_instance_imgid = None
prev_line = None
end_img_id = None

@staticmethod
def start_connection(systemcanvas, instanceobj, img_id):
    ClassName.if_connection_started = True
    ClassName.start_x = instanceobj.coord[0]
    ClassName.start_y = instanceobj.coord[1]
    ClassName.start_instance = instanceobj
    ClassName.start_instance_imgid = img_id
    systemcanvas.bind('<Motion>', lambda event, s = systemcanvas:
    ClassName.motion(s, event))

@staticmethod
def motion(systemcanvas, event):
    if ClassName.if_connection_started:
        ClassName.user_drawn = True
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        if ClassName.prev_line:
            systemcanvas.delete(ClassName.prev_line)
        l = systemcanvas.create_line(ClassName.start_x,
                                     ClassName.start_y,
                                     x, y, width = 5)
        ClassName.prev_line = l
        ClassName.end_img_id = systemcanvas.find_overlapping(event.x,
        event.y, event.x, event.y)
        for id in ClassName.end_img_id:
            if systemcanvas.type(id) == 'image':
                systemcanvas.coords(l,x,y,event.x, event.y)

@staticmethod
def end_connection(systemcanvas, instanceobj, dash):
    systemcanvas.delete(ClassName.prev_line)
    ClassName.prev_line = None
    ClassName.if_connection_started = False
    ClassName.end_x = instanceobj.coord[0]
    ClassName.end_y = instanceobj.coord[1]
    ClassName.start_instance_imgid = None
    if ClassName.start_instance != instanceobj:
        Line(ClassName.start_instance, instanceobj, systemcanvas)
```

Line is another class that draws line from start image to end image.
On single click on image, a method called select_image() is called which in turn calls the function end_connection().

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67256220/13629335) helps.

Comment: Seems like callbacks for `systemcanvas.tag_bind()` are disabled when callback for `systemcanvas.bind()` is active.  Try changing those `systemcanvas.tag_bind()` to `systemcanvas.bind()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I cant follow you. Will you have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67752618/tkinter-canvas-bind-configure-event-to-item). Cause I think using `bind` can have bugs, while `tag_bind` is appropriated.